# How do I download the background image of an HTML5 canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I have a program that randomizes the r, g, and b values for 2 rgb colors and creates a linear gradient mixing the colors. However, the only way I can create that linear gradient is by setting the background-image of my canvas to that gradient, meaning when I download the canvas, it is blank, because the background image isn't dowloaded.

**CSS**

```
.window {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, white, black);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<canvas id = 'randomgradient_canvas' class = 'window'></canvas>
```

**JavaScript**

```
let r1, g1 b1, r2, g2, b2;
function randomizeColors() {
  r1 = Math.random() * 255;
  g1 = Math.random() * 255;
  b1 = Math.random() * 255;
  r2 = Math.random() * 255;
  g2 = Math.random() * 255;
  b2 = Math.random() * 255;
  document.getElementById('randomgradient_canvas').style = `background-image:linear-gradient(to left, rgb(${r1}, ${g1}, ${b1}), rgb(${r2}, ${g2}, ${b2}))`;
}
```

And this all works perfectly for making the gradient, the only problem is I can't find anywhere how to download an element's background image.

Comment: download means?

Comment: is this the purpose of your app? or cant you just generate one online and save it and use it (ref:https://angrytools.com/gradient/image/)?

Comment: Sorry, I guess that wasn't very clear. I meant like how you can right click on a canvas element and bring up the context menu. It includes 'Copy image' and 'Download image'. Normally this would work fine, but the canvas is technically blank; the background image is not. I want to be able to somehow download that background image. It doesn't have to be from the context menu, but even with the toDataURL function, it is still blank.

Comment: And yes, I am creating the app for users to download their own image, not for my own use.

Answer (score 1):

The background defined by CSS is not drawn onto the canvas buffer, thus you can't get the pixel data of it. However, you can draw a gradient to the canvas using [`ctx.createLinearGradient()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/createLinearGradient) and then get the pixel data using [`ctx.getImageData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/getImageData) or something else.